# D3 Legends Are not visible at bottom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to push Legends at bottom of svg chart. but when I try to manipulate x and y position of legends complete graph is not appearing. D3 Js is giving an undefined error. Please find the code inline. Please explain to me how to put legends at the bottom of the chart. Thanks in advance.

```
var colorRange = ["#3366cc", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618", "#990099", 
"#0099c6", "#dd4477", "#66aa00", "#b82e2e", "#316395", "#994499", "#22aa99", 
"#aaaa11", "#6633cc", "#e67300", "#8b0707", "#651067", "#329262", "#5574a6", 
"#3b3eac"];
 var data = [{"name" : "PQR", "percent" : "33.33"},..}]

        // the D3 bits...
        var color = d3.scale.category10();
        var width = 300;
        var height = 700;
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
            return d.percent
        }).sort(null).padAngle(.03);
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(width / 2 * 0.9)
            .innerRadius(width / 2 * 0.5);
        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
            .attr({
                width: width,
                height: height
            })
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        var path = svg.selectAll('path').data(pie(data)) // our data
            .enter().append('path')
            .style('stroke', 'white')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return color(d.data.name)
            });

        path.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var interpolate = d3.interpolate({
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: 0
                }, d);
                return function(t) {
                    return arc(interpolate(t));
                };
            });

        var restOfTheData = function() {
            var text = svg.selectAll('text')
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                })
                .attr("dy", ".4em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.data.percent + "%";
                })
                .style({
                    fill: '#fff',
                    'font-size': '12px'
                });

            var legendRectSize = 20;
            var legendSpacing = 20;

            var legend = d3.select('svg')                           
                        .selectAll("g")
                        .data(color.domain())
                        .enter()
                        .append('g')
                          .attr('class', 'legend')                           
                          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
                            var height = legendRectSize;
                            var x = 0;
                            var y =  i * height;
                            return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
                        });

            legend.append('rect')
                .attr('width', legendRectSize)
                .attr('height', legendRectSize)
                .style('fill', color)
                .style('stroke', color);

            legend.append('text')
                .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
                .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
                .text(function(d) { return d; });
        }
        setTimeout(restOfTheData, 1000);
```

Comment: Is it important that you use version `3`?  The latest version is `5.1.0`.

Comment: No,  But is it possible to achieve this?  If yes please guide me through it

Comment: Well there is an issue at least here: `var y =  i * height;`, each `g` in the legend other than the first will be translated off the svg: the second one will have a translate of [0,700] and your svg is only 700 pixels tall.